# HTMLUnit - Cookie rejected Illegal 'domain' attribute

Tags: htmlunit

First of all I saw similar questions here, but none of them had an actual answer for HTMLUnit and/or are already deprecated.

So HTMLUnit / the underlying apache http client seem to aggressively force the RFC standard, while normal browsers don't care.
I am using version 2.23 of htmlunit and I cannot see any way to set the cookie policy to accept all cookies.

So how can I access the underlying httpclient from htmlunit and change the policy to accept everything (or at least what normal browsers accept too)?

Comment: Can you please add some clarity? Post what cookies you are using?

Comment: @varlogtim From a website which isn't under my control. I try to login there: Cookie rejected [SESS_live="numbersAndDigits", version:0, domain:xyz.com, path:/, expiry:Wed Dec 14 00:20:58 CET 2016] Illegal 'domain' attribute "xyz.com"

Comment: Why not open a issue for HtmlUnit. Provide as many details you have. If you can show that HtmlUnit is different from reals browsers here, there is usually a good chance to get this fixed.